# How to subscribe to items in collection/foreach DOM rendering

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a view that is used to create and also update an item. I have this problem when updating where a function is running twice due to a `change` event on a dropdown list. What was suggested in [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274972/need-a-good-approach-to-conditional-value-changing-asp-net-mvc?noredirect=1#comment50555376_31274972) is that I use a subscription to the value and create logic accordingly within the subscription. I think this is a great idea, however, I have no idea how I will apply these subscriptions to my model when the bindings are being applied dynamically from a view model sent to the view from a back-end controller method.

The collection items get their functionality from data-bind values provided in a `foreach` element loop and using `$data`. It would be preferred to keep this format for the solution.

```
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: koModel.ModelData.Lines">
        <tr class="form-group">
            <td>...</td>
            <td>..other model properties..</td>
            <td>...</td>
            <!-- v v v This is the property with the change event v v v -->
            <td>@Html.SearchPickerMvcKOMultipleFor(
                    m => m.ItemNumber, 
                    "ItemPicker",
                    new { @class = "form-control" }.AddMore(
                        "data-bind", 
                        "MyProgramSearchPicker: ItemNumber, value: $data.ItemNumber, event: { change: ItemNumericDetails($data) }"
                    ))</td>
            <!-- ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ -->
            <td>etc</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

The model is converted to JSON and then to a JavaScript variable:

```
@{ 
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
    string data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model);
    @Html.Raw("var modelData = " + data + ";");
}

var koModel = new KOModel(modelData);
```

**How can I apply a subscription to the ItemNumber property, either by executing an inline function from the element, or another method that can modify a dynamically rendered collection?**

Comment: I would think you might be able to subscribe to `koModel.ModelDate.Lines` and go from there.

Comment: in that case $data.ItemNumber should be an observable property.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that represents a "line" of the `koModel.ModelData.Lines`

```
function Line(itemNumber) {
   var self = this;
   self.ItemNumber = ko.observable(itemNumber);

   self.ItemNumber.subscribe(...);
};

koModel.ModelData.Lines.push(new Line(123));
```

Or, you can create a function in your view model:

```
function koModel() {
   ...
   self.ItemNumericDetails = function (line) {
      //do your job
   };
};
```

and in the HTML:

```
<td>
@Html.SearchPickerMvcKOMultipleFor(
                    m => m.ItemNumber, 
                    "ItemPicker",
                    new { @class = "form-control" }.AddMore(
                        "data-bind", 
                        "MyProgramSearchPicker: ItemNumber, value: $data.ItemNumber, event: { change: $root.ItemNumericDetails }"
                    ))
</td>
```